# moment.js errors

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to replace the functions that I had previously built with date.js, using moment.js. I'm wrapping the dates in moment wrappers like this:

```
var start = moment(new Date(lastLoadDate.getTime()));
var end = moment(new Date(lastLoadDate.getTime()));
```

Then, I'm trying to set Datepicker values based upon lastLoadDate. So, for last month, I'm doing:

```
start = start.day(1);
end = end.day(1).add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);  
// format dates and set DatePicker values
start = start.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
$('.date_from', context).val(start);
end = end.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
$('.date_to', context).val(end);
```

This gives me my first error:

```
end.day(1).add is not a function
```

However, if I take out part of the end date manipulation

```
end = end.day(1);
```

I now get the error:

```
start.format is not a function
```

I'm using moment.min.js version 1.1.0.

Comment: `.day` does not support any arguments according to the source. What are you trying to achieve? https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/master/moment.js

Comment: @pimvdb the docs state otherwise http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulation/day

Comment: Aha: `.day` is only a getter: `function (){return this._d.getDay()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the documentation is wrong, and that function date() should be used instead of day() to set the date. Instead of writing

```
end = end.day(1).add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
```

either

```
end = end.date(1).add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
```

or

```
end.date(1).add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
```

will work, interchangeably.

Comment: I've updated the documentation to fix this. If you find any other problems with the library, feel free to submit an issue at https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/new